# Tailwind CSS unnecessary whitespace

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, inertiajs

I'm trying to use [this admin starter template](https://www.tailwindtoolbox.com/templates/admin-template) I found on the tailwind toolbox and I am trying to customise it to my liking. I've split the code from the template down into 3 separate files, shown below, and when I replace the `children` variable in the main file with something even like `test` I get a scrollbar with lots of extra whitespace at the bottom of the page, as shown here [image: 2]

The 'Main' file which imports the navbar and sidebar and then also has a placeholder for the main page content

```
import Navbar from "@/Components/Layouts/Navbar"
import Sidebar from "@/Components/Layouts/Sidebar"

export default function Main({ name, children }) {

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-800 flex flex-col h-screen">

      <Navbar />

      <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row flex-grow">

        <Sidebar />

        <div className="flex-1 bg-gray-100">
          <div className="bg-gray-800 pt-3">
            <div className="rounded-tl-3xl bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-900 to-gray-800 p-4 shadow text-2xl text-white">
              <h3 className="font-bold pl-2">{name}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="p-4">
            {children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The navbar

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Navbar() {
  const [dropdownState, setDropdownState] = useState('invisible');

  const toggleDropdown = () => {
    console.log('toggle');
    if (dropdownState) {
      setDropdownState(null);
    } else {
      setDropdownState('invisible')
    }
  }

  return (
    < nav className="bg-gray-800 pt-2 md:pt-1 pb-1 px-1 mt-0 h-auto sticky w-full z-20 top-0" >

      <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center">
        <div className="flex flex-shrink md:w-1/3 justify-center md:justify-start text-white">
          <a href="#">
            <span className="text-xl pl-2"><i className="em em-grinning"></i></span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-1 md:w-1/3 justify-center md:justify-start text-white px-2">
          <span className="relative w-full">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search"
              className="w-full bg-gray-900 text-white transition border border-transparent focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-400 rounded py-3 px-2 pl-10 appearance-none leading-normal" />
            <div className="absolute search-icon" style={{ top: "1rem", left: ".8rem" }}>
              <svg className="fill-current pointer-events-none text-white w-4 h-4"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                <path
                  d="M12.9 14.32a8 8 0 1 1 1.41-1.41l5.35 5.33-1.42 1.42-5.33-5.34zM8 14A6 6 0 1 0 8 2a6 6 0 0 0 0 12z">
                </path>
              </svg>
            </div>
          </span>
        </div>

        <div className="flex w-full pt-2 content-center justify-between md:w-1/3 md:justify-end">
          <ul className="list-reset flex justify-between flex-1 md:flex-none items-center">
            <li className="flex-1 md:flex-none md:mr-3">
              <a className="inline-block py-2 px-4 text-white no-underline" href="#">Active</a>
            </li>
            <li className="flex-1 md:flex-none md:mr-3">
              <a className="inline-block text-gray-600 no-underline hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-underline py-2 px-4"
                href="#">link</a>
            </li>
            <li className="flex-1 md:flex-none md:mr-3">
              <div className="relative inline-block">
                <button onClick={toggleDropdown} className="drop-button text-white focus:outline-none">
                  <span className="pr-2"><i className="em em-robot_face"></i></span> Hi, User <svg
                    className="h-3 fill-current inline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                    <path
                      d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z" />
                  </svg></button>
                <div id="myDropdown"
                  className={"dropdownlist absolute bg-gray-800 text-white right-0 mt-3 p-3 overflow-auto z-30 " + dropdownState}>
                  <a href="#"
                    className="p-2 hover:bg-gray-800 text-white text-sm no-underline hover:no-underline block"><i
                      className="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Profile</a>
                  <a href="#"
                    className="p-2 hover:bg-gray-800 text-white text-sm no-underline hover:no-underline block"><i
                      className="fa fa-cog fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                  <div className="border border-gray-800"></div>
                  <a href="#"
                    className="p-2 hover:bg-gray-800 text-white text-sm no-underline hover:no-underline block"><i
                      className="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-fw"></i> Log Out</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav >
  )
}
```

and the sidebar

```
import { InertiaLink } from "@inertiajs/inertia-react"

export default function Sidebar() {
  const linkClass = (route) => {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(route) !== -1) {
      return ' border-blue-600'
    } else {
      return ' border-gray-800'
    }
  }

  const iconClass = (route) => {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(route) !== -1) {
      return ' text-blue-600'
    }
  }

  const textClass = (route) => {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(route) !== -1) {
      return ' text-white md:text-white'
    } else {
      return ' text-gray-600 md:text-gray-400'
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-800 shadow-xl h-16 fixed bottom-0 mt-12 md:relative md:h-screen z-10 w-full md:w-48">
      <div
        className="md:mt-12 md:w-48 md:fixed md:left-0 md:top-0 content-center md:content-start text-left justify-between">
        <ul className="list-reset flex flex-row md:flex-col py-0 md:py-3 px-1 md:px-2 text-center md:text-left">
          <li className="mr-3 flex-1">
            <InertiaLink href="/owner/dashboard"
              className={"block py-1 md:py-3 pl-1 align-middle text-white no-underline hover:text-white border-b-2 hover:border-blue-900"
              + linkClass('/owner/dashboard')}>
              <i className={"fas fa-tv pr-2 "
              + iconClass('/owner/dashboard')}></i><span
                className={"pb-1 md:pb-0 text-xs md:text-base block md:inline-block"
                + textClass('/owner/dashboard')}>Dashboard</span>
            </InertiaLink>
          </li>
          <li className="mr-3 flex-1">
            <InertiaLink href="/owner/restaurants"
              className={"block py-1 md:py-3 pl-1 align-middle text-white no-underline hover:text-white border-b-2 hover:border-blue-900"
              + linkClass('/owner/restaurants')}>
              <i className={"fa fa-utensils pr-2 "
              + iconClass('/owner/restaurants')}></i><span
                className={"pb-1 md:pb-0 text-xs md:text-base block md:inline-block"
                + textClass('/owner/restaurants')}>Restaurants</span>
            </InertiaLink>
          </li>
          <li className="mr-3 flex-1">
            <a href="#"
              className={"block py-1 md:py-3 pl-1 align-middle text-white no-underline hover:text-white border-b-2 hover:border-blue-900"
              + linkClass('/owner/layouts')}>
              <i className={"fas fa-pencil-ruler pr-2 "
              + iconClass('/owner/layouts')}></i><span
                className={"pb-1 md:pb-0 text-xs md:text-base block md:inline-block"
                + textClass('/owner/layouts')}>Layouts</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="mr-3 flex-1">
            <a href="#"
              className={"block py-1 md:py-3 pl-0 md:pl-1 align-middle text-white no-underline hover:text-white border-b-2 hover:border-blue-900"
              + linkClass('/owner/payments')}>
              <i className={"fa fa-wallet pr-2 "
              + iconClass('/owner/payments')}></i><span
                className={"pb-1 md:pb-0 text-xs md:text-base block md:inline-block"
                + textClass('/owner/payments')}>Payments</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is a link to a codepen with the code to assist with debugging https://codepen.io/hcphoon01/pen/OJmXrRN

**UPDATE** I've now fixed one issue but created another, I have fixed the whitespace issue by changing the highest level div to `<div className="bg-gray-800 flex flex-col h-screen">` and then adding `flex-grow` on the div above where the sidebar is included, although now the issue is that if the content is larger than the screen, the sidebar does not grow to fit. The codepen has been updated to reflect this

Comment: Please create a code sandbox for easier debugging. Or just use your inspector to check the css directly.
From what you've given, I'm guessing when you set the sidebar to h-screen then give your other components margins, it is pushing the page to be even longer than the height of the screen. Try adjusting your margins.

Answer (score 3):

Check your `Sidebar` component.
It must be `h-auto` or `h-full` or `h-initial` instead `h-screen`. because it placed into `main` component, so only `main` should be `h-screen`.

please change this code instead of use `h-screen`.

```
<div class="bg-gray-800 shadow-xl h-16 bottom-0 mt-12 md:relative z-10 w-full md:w-48">
```

check on [Tailwind Paly](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0CX1HkkrcU)

More information about Viewport units in CSS, check this web [doc](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/unexpected-power-of-viewport-units-in-css)

Comment: I've just tried that, but the issue now is that if I add `h-screen` to the top level div, to remove [this issue](https://i.imgur.com/e9wh4DP.png), and then add `h-screen` to the div just below where the sidebar is included, to allow the main content to be the full height, I have the same issue again with the whitespace at the bottom

Comment: check edited. and you can adjust with your fix in there.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the `h-screen` class, it sets the height to be `100vh`, which will span the height of the viewport. The problem here is that since we are fixing the height, the `<div>` will not grow to fit its children and things will overflow.

To fix this, we can set [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) instead, with the `min-h-screen` utility class. This will allow the `<div>` to grow to fit its children but prevent it from shrinking below the viewport height. I tried this out in your provided CodePen and it seems to do what you want.

Note: There are some quirks with using `100vh` on mobile. Just search for "100vh mobile issue" to find more information, but you should test it out to see if this behavior is what you want. Alternatively, you can use percentage units with `h-full`/`min-h-full`, but you'll have to make sure that all of the ancestors have `height`/`min-height` set to 100%, including the `<body>` and `<html>` tags. Test things out on various mobile browsers for yourself to figure out which one works better for your application.

Answer (score 0):

On the parent div in the main file add and m-0 p-0 to the className and on the div for "Test" add whitespace-normal to the className as illustrated below :

```
import Navbar from "@/Components/Layouts/Navbar"
import Sidebar from "@/Components/Layouts/Sidebar"

export default function Main({ name, children }) {

  return (
    <div className="m-0 p-0 bg-gray-800 flex flex-col h-screen">

      <Navbar />

      <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row flex-grow">

        <Sidebar />

        <div className="flex-1 bg-gray-100">
          <div className="bg-gray-800 pt-3">
            <div className="rounded-tl-3xl bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-900 to-gray-800 p-4 shadow text-2xl text-white">
              <h3 className="font-bold pl-2">{name}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="p-4 whitespace-normal">
            Test
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```